# ASP.NET network issue

Tags: asp.net

So i want to to create a web application using asp.net to connect to another application (for example a simple windows form) using sockets. The problem is i'm behind firewall and i don't have the authority to mess with the firewall settings, what other options can i do besides sockets?

My application is fairly simple, the web application will be hosted on the internet and has a "connect" button, when its click it establish connection with the windows form that is on another computer and display the message "Connected" if its connected.  All this will be tested behind some kind of corporal firewall. How do i get around this?

Comment: Accepted 0 of 20 questions? You might want to look into that ...

Answer (score 1):

The firewall is there specifically to stop this kind of thing.

The bestway around it would be to have the Forms app poll the server for connectivity - this can be made to look near real time by making the server receive the request, then wait until it gets a connect action, or time out after a few minutes and return nothing.  Then the forms app would request again.

Comment: But how can it make the connection if the firewall doesnt allow it? I used sockets and tested using visual studio web develper, using thier server it worked fine on the local network but when hosted the website on the internet, firewall doesnt allow the connection

Comment: I was thinking if i hook up both computers through the ethernet cable instead of wireless, will that solve the network issue even if the website if hosted on the internet?

Comment: He's suggesting the client app connects to the web app using a web request. If the firewall on the web server won't allow outbound connections and you can't change that, you'll have to call in instead. No, the connection mechanism shouldn't make a difference - unless your network policy has different firewall settings for different connection types? I'd be surprised if it did.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using directly a web application, you should look forward to create a web service to solve both the purposes. You can have its reference in both of them. your Web Form will make a request **to connect to the web service** instead of application. That will solve both purposes.